# Multiple iterations over a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

For each site and month, I'm trying to calculate the sum of values at nearby sites using a Pandas DataFrame and three loops. The initial DataFrame is df1, below.

```
| Site name | Lat   | Lon    | March 2018 | April 2018 | May 2018 |
|-----------|-------|--------|------------|------------|----------|
| A         | 10.0  | 15.0   | 1          | 2          | 3        |
| B         | 10.1  | 15.0   | 1          | 2          | 3        |
| C         | 12.0  | 100.0  | 1          | 2          | 3        |
```

Loop 1) Start at first column containing data
Loop 2) Grab coordinates of first site to compare with all other sites
Loop 3) Compare coordinates of first site with each site; if distance between them (calculated using the Haversine formula, not listed) less than **Rtarget**, add to **msum**, which is the monthly sum of values at all sites within **Rtarget** distance of the initial site.

The output goes to empty DataFrame, df2, with identical index and columns as df1. With each iteration through loop 2, there should be a final value, **msum**, which should be entered into the same location (index and column) in df2 as was taken in loop 2.

My code currently produces df2 that looks like this:

```
            | Lat | Lon | March 2018 | April 2018 | May 2018 |
| Site name |-----|-----|------------|------------|----------|
| A         | 0   | 0   | 0          | 0          | 0        |
| B         | 0   | 0   | 0          | 0          | 0        |
| C         | 0   | 0   | 3          | 6          | 9        |
```

While df2 should look like this instead:

```
            | Lat | Lon | March 2018 | April 2018 | May 2018 |
| Site name |-----|-----|------------|------------|----------|
| A         | 0   | 0   | 2          | 4          | 6        |
| B         | 0   | 0   | 2          | 4          | 6        |
| C         | 0   | 0   | 1          | 2          | 3        |
```

My code is below:

```
# Create empty data frame with identical columns
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

Rtarget = 500  # Set the target distance to X miles

# Iterate through each month of data
for column, row in df.iloc[:,2:].iteritems():

    # Select the initial site and define the starting coordinates
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        lat01 = row['Latitude']
        lon01 = row['Longitude']
        msum = 0 # set monthly sum equal to zero

        # Iterate through each comparison site and define comparison coordinates
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            lat02 = row['Latitude']
            lon02 = row['Longitude']
            distance = haversine(lon01, lat01, lon02, lat02) 
            if distance <= Rtarget: 
                msum += row[column] # Add the value to the monthly sum

    # Place monthly sum into the corresponding location in the empty dataframe, df1
    df1[column][index] = msum
```

What am I missing that causes all the rows but the final row to remain empty?

Comment: What is your expected outcome? 
It seems to me like all the values of the column are summed up in the last row, idk what you expect the other rows to be

Comment: Please try pasting the dataframes anyway, if there is something wrong we can help you with that. Also instead of all that code, tell us what you're trying to do and the output you expect.

Comment: Well--damnit, I solved it, and it was a silly error, of course. My variables in the 3 loops overlapped and interrupted one another. Thanks for looking at my problem and commenting, it made me rethink my code presentation!